# C: Accessing (int) via (void *) pointing to (void *) pointing to (int) by typecasting and dereferencing

Tags: c, void-pointers

I'm fiddling around with pointers in C and am still uncertain about some very basics. I came up with the following exemplary code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num = 42;              // we want to access this integer
    void *vptrB = &num;        // pointer B points to the integer
    void *vptrA = &vptrB;      // pointer A points to pointer B
    printf("%d\n", * (int *) * (void **) vptrA);
    return 0;
}
```

The memory should look something like this:

[image: scheme]

Are there alternatives to access the integer? Anything bad/unsafe with the example? Is `* (int *) * (void **) vptrA` the only way to access `num` via `vptrA` and `vptrB`?

Comment: Why are you keeping your pointers as `void *` instead of using the correct types?  You should try to work *with* the type system, not fight it.

Comment: Ouch; remind me not to need to read your code in future, please?  That's painful to understand.  If you can reference `vptrB`, then you can make it simpler, but if you can only access `vptrA`, then what you've written looks correct — but I've not run it past a compiler to double check that I've interpreted it the same as a compiler would.

Comment: I would say it's bad style to use `void*` in general (especially in places where you could easily use a typed pointer), and very bad style to disguise the level of indirection involved (i.e. storing the address of a `void*` instead of a `void**`). And I'd normally avoid casting in the middle of dereferencing, so I'd have `**((int**) vptrA)`.

Comment: @TomKarzes: I'm sure this is just an exercise in understanding convoluted pointers rather than anything else.  I certainly hope it is not indicative of how production code will be written.

Comment: Well, for what it's worth, the code does look "correct" to me.  It's just painful to deal with the `void *` references.  But normally you only want to use `void *` in situations where you have to accommodate multiple pointer types, and of course you always cast them back to their proper types before dereferencing them.

Comment: @Zastai, unfortunately, although your approach probably works on many systems, it is not *guaranteed* to work on every system, because pointers to different types are not certain to be the same size or to have the same representation.  To be safe, you need to perform the string of conversions and derferences that the OP presented.

Comment: @Zastai What OP has is correct.  What you suggest is not.  The casts need to be there since casting to/from `void *` can change the representation.

Comment: I concur with the others that the string of casts and dereferences is *"painful to understand"* and *"bad style"*. It would be better to unwrap the pointer one step at a time on separate lines and trust the optimizer to eliminate the intermediate steps. So `void *vptr = *(void **)vptrA; int n = *(int *)vptr;` and then print `n`.

Comment: @Zastai your suggestion violates the strict aliasing rule

Comment: What is the question exactly? "Are there alternatives to access the integer?", yes, obviously you could write `num`,  or `int *p = &num;` ... `*p` or a thousand and one other things. Mostly not involving creating `vptrA` and `vptrB` in the first place.

Comment: The question was `Are there alternatives to access the integer?` and he obviously forgot that `printf("%d\n", num);` would work equally well...and is much more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there alternatives to access the integer?

```
 int num = 42;
 int *vptrB = &num;
 int **vptrA = &vptrB;
 // All print 42
 printf("%d\n", num);
 printf("%d\n", *vptrB);
 printf("%d\n", **vptrA);
```

> Anything bad/unsafe with the example?

Use of `void*` to represent the address to data loses type, alignment, `const` and `volatile` information.  `void*` obliges the use of casting to subsequently interpret the referenced data - this is prone to error.  Although the code is correct in its casting, it is subject to maintenance mistakes and code review mis-understandings.

Comment: using `void *` without casts does preserve `const` and `volatile` info.   Of course you can cast those things away but that is also true for `int *`